# XNA - Link between Create Rotations

Tags: c#, matrix, xna

A friend of mine have been coding some rotations on my XNA project, but the order of the matrices rotation are not good.
Some are of form :

```
Matrix.CreateRotationZ(1.21f) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(-0.13f)
```

and other:

```
Matrix.CreateRotationY(1.01f) * Matrix.CreateRotationX(-0.5f) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(0.80f)
```

How can I find the values X, Y, Z so the rotations are in the correct order: (X,Y,Z)

```
Matrix.CreateRotationX(X) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(Y) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Z)
```

Comment: Why do you want to change the order? Maybe there is a reason why he coded it this way? Anyway, you could calculate the overall matrix and convert it to euler angles with any algorithm you find on the internet.